# BIML assigns wrong metadata to NUMBER columns from Oracle

Tags: ssis, biml

I've successfully created a BIML script on BIDS 2008 with BIDS Helper 1.6.6.0 which automates the creation of SSIS packages to import data from an Oracle database (11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit) into SQL Server 2008 R2. I am having an issue at package run-time which causes the package to fail at Data Flow valdation with:

> Warning: The external columns for component "Source" (1) are out of synchronization with the data source columns. The external column "LIMIT_AMOUNT" needs to be updated.
>   The external column "LIMIT_BASE_AMOUNT" needs to be updated.
>   The external column "GROSS_BASE_AMOUNT" needs to be updated.
>
> Error: The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_BYTES" and "DT_NUMERIC" for "LIMIT_AMOUNT".
>
> Error: The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_BYTES" and "DT_NUMERIC" for "LIMIT_BASE_AMOUNT".
>
> Error: The OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_BYTES" and "DT_NUMERIC" for "GROSS_BASE_AMOUNT".
>
> Error: There were errors during task validation.

Upon inspection, it appears that the metadata for `NUMBER` columns without scale and precision in Oracle are mapped to `DT_BYTES` in the generated SSIS. The description of the above object (a view) in Oracle is as follows:

```
Name                  Null Type         
--------------------- ---- ------------ 
ID                         NUMBER(12)
CURRENCY                   VARCHAR2(3)  
LIMIT_AMOUNT               NUMBER       
LIMIT_BASE_AMOUNT          NUMBER       
GROSS_BASE_AMOUNT          NUMBER       
STATUS                     VARCHAR2(15)
```

Checking in `all_tab_columns` shows the three `NUMBER` columns as having a `DATA_LENGTH` of 22 and NULL `DATA_PRECISION` and `DATA_SCALE`.

```
 COLUMN_ID COLUMN_NAME            DATA_TYPE     DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
---------- ---------------------- ------------- ----------- -------------- ----------
         1 ID                     NUMBER                 22             12          0 
         2 CURRENCY               VARCHAR2                3                           
         3 LIMIT_AMOUNT           NUMBER                 22                           
         4 LIMIT_BASE_AMOUNT      NUMBER                 22                           
         5 GROSS_BASE_AMOUNT      NUMBER                 22                           
         6 STATUS                 VARCHAR2               15
```

The [Oracle documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/oracle-integer-to-number-conversion) states that this is the equivalent of a `float`

> Specify a floating-point number using the following form:
>
> `NUMBER`
>
> The absence of precision and scale designators specifies the maximum range and precision for an Oracle number.

The workaround so far was to implement a custom SELECT which casts these fields to the desired type, but that's not very elegant or maintainable. I would like to understand why BIML seems to get the data type mapping wrong, whereas SSIS is able to determine that the metadata is wrong when the package is first opened after it has been created –I get a pop-up in BIDS stating that

> The metadata of the following output columns does not match the metadata of the external columns with which the output columns are associated:
>
> Output "Output":    "LIMIT_AMOUNT", "LIMIT_BASE_AMOUNT", "GROSS_EXP_BASE_AMOUNT"
>
> Do you want to replace the metadata of the output columns with the metadata of the external columns?

EDIT: Adding relevant Biml details regarding connections & dataflow

```biml
<#
string OraConnectionStr = @"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(In-line TNS);User Id=redacted;Password=redacted;Persist Security Info=True;";
string StagingConnectionStr = "Data Source=SVR;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=SQLNCLI10;";
#>

<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <Connection Name="<#=StagingConnectionName#>" 
                    ConnectionString="<#=StagingConnectionStr#>" />
        <Connection Name="<#=OraConnectionName#>" 
                    ConnectionString="<#=OraConnectionStr#>" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
    <!-- Assume object stagingTables is populated and methods have been defined -->
    <# foreach (DataRow row in stagingTables.Rows) { #>
        <Package Name="<#= GetChildPackageName(row) #>"
                 ConstraintMode="Linear" AutoCreateConfigurationsType="None">
          <Dataflow Name="<#=GetStagingTableDescriptiveName(row)#>" >
            <Tasks>
              <Transformations>
                <OleDbSource Name="Source - <#=GetStagingTableDescriptiveName(row)#>"
                             ConnectionName="<#=OraConnectionName#>" 
                             AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage="true"
                             DefaultCodePage="1252">
                  <DirectInput>SELECT * FROM <#GetOracleObjectName(row)#></DirectInput>
                </OleDbSource>
                <OleDbDestination Name="Destination - <#=GetStagingTableDescriptiveName(row)#>" 
                                  ConnectionName="<#=DataLoadConnectionName#>">
                    <ExternalTableOutput Table="<#= GetStagingTableObjectName(row) #>" />
                </OleDbDestination>
              </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
          </Tasks>
        </Package>
      <# } #>
    </Packages
</Biml>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Oracle provider are you using? Which version are you going up against? Can you post your Biml so we can see the source?

Comment: @billinkc - I've edited the question with relevant Biml including provider & dataflow. Server reports Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

Comment: We have had a little more success using the [Microsoft Drivers by Attunity](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283)  or the 2014 Versions [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582)

Comment: I think this is more an Oracle OLEDB driver issue than BIML engine per se. That being said... 

When using GetDropAndCreateDdl() to generate the new SQL Server DDL from oracle tables:

NUMBER() -> DT_I8 -> BIGINT

...but when generating the data flows, the Oracle NUMBER fields from the tables in my OleDbSource, using <ExternalTableInput> for the tables, doesn't seem to do the same column mapping though, causing the observed behavior by the original poster.

BimlExpress 2019, Oracle 12.2C client, VS 2017 15.9.12, MS SSIS Projects extension 2.3

Comment: ...the real kicker is discovering floating point values in some of those NUMBER() fields in Oracle. So I ID'd those particular columns and after creating the tables, I added a ExecuteSQL task to that package to alter them to DECIMAL(19,4). I then made sure the biml that sets up the data the data flows makes them not fail on Truncation...

Comment: I am having the same problem with Datetime Field. Did you find a way to overcome this problem?